# Creating a new array of objects from an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I feel like this should be easy, but I can't figure it out.

To simplify, I need to dynamically generate an array. Then I need my code to build a list of objects based off the middle of that array.

```
array = [a, b, c, d];
start = array[0];
finish = array[array.length - 1];
middle = [
  { middle: array[1] },
  { middle: array[2] }
]
```

I need this to be dynamic, so I can't hardcode my middle values due to the array length not being set in stone. I assumed I needed a `loop` function to iterate through my array, but I've never used this for anything but creating a list in the DOM. I feel like I'm overthinking this or something, because this should be easy... everything I do breaks my code though.

my latest attempt was:

```
middle = [
  for (i = 1; i < array.length - 2; i++) {
    return { middle: array[i] };
  }
]
```

I think I get why it doesn't work. It just returns what I want, but I don't think that value ever gets stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just adjusting @chazsolo's answer to your expected output with a mapping to your target format.

```js
const array = [1,2,3,4,5];
const middle = array.slice(1, -1).map(item => ({middle: item}));
console.log(middle);
```

Comment: Good call, I didn't match his expected output

Comment: Man I feel dumb. Ya, just storing that in a variable, and then running that variable where I needed it was all I needed. I was completely overthinking it. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

Use `slice` to grab the values you're looking for

```js
const array = [1,2,3,4,5];
const middle = array.slice(1, -1);

console.log(middle);
```

This returns a new array containing every value except for the first and the last.

---

If you don't, or can't, use `map`, then you can still use a `for` loop:

```js
const array = [1,2,3,4,5];
const middle = array.slice(1, -1);

for (let i = 0; i < middle.length; i++) {
  middle[i] = {
    middle: middle[i]
  };
}

console.log(middle);
```

Comment: I think the problem with this is I need to format that middle array as an array of objects. I'm not really struggling to get the middle values as much as I'm struggling to reformat the information in a way that the code reads it like the first example.

Comment: @sjahan's answer is more complete in that regard. You just need to map each value to your expected format.

Answer (score 0):

Define an array and push whatever you want to push into it.

```js
let array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
let middles = []
for (i = 1; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
  middles.push({ middle: array[i] })
}
console.log(middles)
```

In case you want to learn more, check [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)